# XSSFCell Cell with period

Tags: java, xssf

I am using this library with Java and trying to parse an excel file. A few of my cells just have ... in them. When the parser hits this cell, it does not detect anything in it and continues on. It is a test cell and I am using the getStringValue. Any ideas on why this would be happening? I have put in a fail clause to fail if it sees it and it wont trigger

```
if (curCell.getStringCellValue().equals("...")) {
    fail("Could be a trim issue");
}
```

Thanks

Comment: If you open the workbook in Excel and click on one of these cells, what do you see in the formula bar?

Comment: If I click on the cell, yes I do see the ... in it

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out the problem. It appears that excel does something funny with cells that have ... in it. So ... is 3 characters. Excel was converting it into 1 character. This was my problem. Once I copied and pasted that 1 character ..., I was able to replace it with the 3 char ...